# Updating a PySpark dataframe column with an RDD of tuples

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am working with data where user info is string. I would like to assign unique integer values to those strings.

I was somewhat following this stack overflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772769/how-to-use-mllib-recommendation-if-the-user-ids-are-string-instead-of-contiguous). I am using the expression below to have an RDD of tuples:

```
user = data.map(lambda x:x[0]).distinct().zipWithUniqueId()
```

After that, I did

```
data = data.map(lambda x: Rating(int(user.lookup(x[0])), int(x[1]), float(x[2])))
```

What I ultimately want to do is run an ALS model on it, but so far I have been getting this error message

> Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation.

I think the data type is somehow wrong, but I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: There is 2 issues here. The first one is wanting to update values in a DataFrame, that's impossible ! DataFrame are immutable, you'll have to create a new one from the existing one with the update transformation. Second, you can't nest an RDD inside another RDD transformation. You might consider broadcast variable if your RDD is small.

Comment: @eliasah thank you for your input. will newData = data.map(lambda x: Rating(int(user.lookup(x[0])), int(x[1]), float(x[2]))) work, or do I have to do something like df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(?, [cols]), where I am not quite sure how to put stuff in the place of ?. As for the second part, where am I nesting an RDD inside another RDD transformation? My data is quite big actually.

Comment: That may work, you'll need to try ! I can't read code in comment. As for the second part, your user value is an RDD. So here is where you are try to nest RDD.

Answer (score 1):

`lookup` approach suggested in the linked answer is simply invalid. Spark doesn't support nested action nor transformations so you cannot call `RDD.lookup` inside a `map`. If data is to large to be handled using a standard Python `dict` for lookups you can simply `join` and reshape:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import Rating

data = sc.parallelize([("foo", 1, 2.0), ("bar", 2, 3.0)])

user = itemgetter(0)

def to_rating(record):
    """
    >>> to_rating((("foobar", 99, 5.0), 1000))
    Rating(user=1000, product=99, rating=5.0)
    """
    (_, item, rating), user = record
    return Rating(user, item, rating)

user_lookup = data.map(user).distinct().zipWithIndex()

ratings = (data
    .keyBy(user)  # Add user string as a key
    .join(user_lookup)  # Join with lookup
    .values()  # Drop keys
    .map(to_rating))  # Create Ratings

ratings.first()
## Rating(user=1, product=1, rating=2.0)
```